# Available instant messaging clients

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation, instant-messaging

Am looking for an all-round Messenger for Ubuntu, especially one that supports Webcam, Voice Chat, Microphone, Drag/Drop support, File sending and other normal operations a messenger should have. I have tried Amsn, Kmess, Emesene, Pidgin and I am currently using Emesene. What messenger client would you recommend and what features do they offer in terms of:

- Webcam
- Voice Chat
- Drag & Drop Support
- File Upload/Download
- Emoticons
- Skin Theme
- Ubuntu Notification Compatibility
- Compatibility With other Messengers
- Updated Messenger (There are many that their last update was when Star Trek 1 came out)
- Compatibility with Email services (Sites like Yahoo, Hotmail or Google and their services like Google talk)
- Any other you can think of.

What (unique?) features does your messenger client offer?

NOTE - I have posted some messengers from a little over 2 years of experience with each (I normally install several messengers) to help anybody that wants to try any of them.

Comment: forget about using your webcam for video chat other than skype own IM there's no other way of doing video chat+IM

Comment: Pidgin perhaps? It has more features and options than the default Empathy messenger. I prefer to use Empathy because it's simple and looks nice. I don't need that much features. As the above comment said, if I want to video chat with someone, I use Skype or GMail. When I was still using KDE, Kopete really rocked! I missed that thing. :)

Comment: @Uri - I can vouch for Amsn having webcam support and also Empathy. Other like Emesene and Kmess I am waiting.

Comment: do they still work?!, amazing, i mean does videochat works when using the msn protocl?

Comment: Empathy as far as i know works on the gtalk. On the msn one it does not but since I have not used the msn one since i moved my account to gmail for a better mail experience all around, for me, I do not care much about what msn does ;) (Besides, using hotmail for me is like hell, very confusing, not friendly and the page looks like an old html simple page that got married with 200 ads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Empathy

**Webcam Support** - Yes
**MSN Full Support** - Yes (No Webcam, Voice Chat)
**GTalk Full Support** - Yes  (Including Voice Chat, Video Chat to Cellular phones)
**Voice Chat** - Yes
**Protocols Supported** - Multiple (GTalk, Msn, Yahoo...)
**Send Files** - Yes
**Receive Files** - Yes
**Emoticons** - Yes
**Theme/Skin** - Yes (Only Chat)
**Language Support** - Yes
**Drag & Drop Support** - Yes
**Ubuntu Notification Support** - Yes
**Last Updated (Since this Post)** - Version 3.0.0 - April 4, 2011
**Found in Ubuntu Repository** - Yes (Version 2.34.0-0ubuntu3)
**Now Playing Support** - Yes (With extensions)
**Plugins** - No
**PRO** - Very compatible. Easy to use. Remote Desktop Shared
**CON** - No Plugin List, No custom theme.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

## Pidgin

**Webcam Support** - Yes
**MSN Full Support** - Yes
**GTalk Full Support** - Yes
**Voice Chat** - Yes
**Protocols Supported** - Multiple (GTalk, Msn, Yahoo...)
**Send Files** - Yes
**Receive Files** - Yes
**Emoticons** - Yes
**Theme/Skin** - Yes
**Language Support** - Yes
**Drag & Drop Support** - Yes
**Ubuntu Notification Support** - Yes
**Last Updated (Since this Post)** - Version 2.7.11 - March 11, 2011
**Found in Ubuntu Repository** - Yes (Version 1:2.7.11-1ubuntu2)
**Now Playing Support** - Yes (With several players like Banshee)
**Plugins** - Yes
**PRO** - Very compatible.
**CON** - Very simple/"old like" to the eye.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### Emesene

**Webcam Support** - Yes
**MSN Full Support** - Yes
**GTalk Full Support** - No
**Voice Chat** - No
**Protocols Supported** - MSN Protocol Only (With Plugins GTalk,Facebook can be used)
**Send Files** - Yes
**Receive Files** - Yes
**Emoticons** - Yes
**Theme/Skin** - Yes
**Language Support** - Yes
**Drag & Drop Support** - Yes
**Ubuntu Notification Support** - Yes
**Last Updated (Since this Post)** - Version 2.11.5 - May 30, 2011
**Found in Ubuntu Repository** - Yes (Version 2.11.4+dfsg-0ubuntu1)
**Now Playing Support** - Not Yet
**Plugins** - Yes
**PRO** - MSN Live Messenger Style, Easy to use/setup, Friendly
**CON** - No Full Video/Audio Support for all protocols

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### [Qnext](http://www.qnext.com/)

---

*Qnext is an multi-protocol Instant Messengers for Windows, Mac, Linux and Mobile. Qnext lets people connect to their digital content when they have access to the internet.*

---

[image: Qnext]

All clients are freeware.

- **Desktop** Client available for Mac, Windows and Linux computers.
- **An iPhone , iPod touch and iPad Application** that can be downloaded from the Apple store.
- **A Mobile Web** version and can be used
  with an WebKit based browser.

Qnext services run in a multi-tasking mode, which allows users to carry multiple tasks at the same time, such as talking to a group using video, transfer files, download files, view content, share content, carry IM conversation with others and more.

### Qnext Desktop (PC) Client Features

- Multi-protocol (universal) Instant
  Messaging for Facebook, MySpace,
  Windows Live Messenger (MSN), ICQ,
  AOL , Yahoo! Messenger, Google Talk,
  Jabber (XMPP) and iChat sends and
  receives IM messages and keeps users
  truly connected to everyone from a
  single contact list.
- Qnext File transfer is a fast and
  secured way to get a file or folder
  of any size to any Qnext user and
  puts an end to using FTP or sending
  CD’s via courier or dealing with
  email attachment limitations. Just
  drag and drop any file or folder of
  any size on anyone on your contact
  list, and you’re done. The recipient
  will receive a message to allow the
  transfer and the content will be
  transferred. Files are sent using SSL
  encryption via peer to peer (P2P)
  connection directly to the recipient
  computer.
- Voice chat (Audio conferencing) is
  multi-user voice conferencing (up to
  eight people at once). Qnext uses
  direct P2P routing to find the best
  available network connection; the
  quality of the user’s online
  "telephone" call is high. Mac,
  Windows, and Linux users can all jump
  on a Video or Voice call togethe
- Video conferencing is a multi-user
  Video Chat (up to four people at
  once). This is where individuals or
  groups from around the world can meet
  face to face in real time, to
  interact for as long as they want,
  without any costs. Initiating a video
  conference is straightforward and
  easy. Qnext automatically detects
  video & sound devices.
- Photo sharing is a way to share
  photos with anyone in seconds, even
  if the recipients don’t have Qnext.
- File sharing is a great way to get
  those huge files where they need to
  go fast.
- Streaming media (Music) allows to
  listen to your entire music library
  and iTunes or Media Player playlists
  from anywhere in the world.

**Qnext for Linux**

- **How to Install**
- Download Qnext
- Decompress the downloaded archive and launch the application

  ```
   tar -xf qnextsetup.tgz 
   cd qnext
   ./qnext!
  ```

[image: Wizard]

[image: Protocols Used]

[image: Main Window]

[image: Conversation Window]

Source: http://www.qnext.com/ & http://en.wikipedia.com/

Answer (score 3):

### Amsn

**Webcam Support** - Not Yet (Until Version 0.99)
**MSN Full Support** - Not Yet (Until Version 0.99)
**GTalk Full Support** - No
**Voice Chat** - Not Yet (Until Version 0.99)
**Protocols Supported** - MSN Protocol Only
**Send Files** - Yes (Sometimes slow to start)
**Receive Files** - Yes (Sometimes slow to start)
**Emoticons** - Yes
**Theme/Skin** - Yes
**Language Support** - Yes
**Drag & Drop Support** - Not Yet (Until Version 0.99)
**Ubuntu Notification Support** - No (It shows its own Notification Window)
**Last Updated (Since this Post)** - Version 0.98 - December 8, 2010
**Found in Ubuntu Repository** - Yes (Version 0.98.4-0ubuntu1)
**Now Playing Support** - Yes (With several players like Banshee)
**Plugins** - Yes
**PRO** - Easy to use/setup, Many options for connection, contacts
**CON** - Slow

[image]

Comment: Please make each of these clients as a new answer so people can cast votes on their favorites

Comment: This was the first one i tried. It was good until i met with Kmess and how it looked.

Answer (score 2):

### Jitsi

Consider [Jitsi](https://www.jitsi.org/), it's multi-platform and LGPL.

[image: Jitsi]

[image: Video conference]

[image: Jitsi Features]

Cons: It's based on Java and looks ugly, does not  respect the current theme and start-up is slow.

Answer (score 1):

### Kmess

**Webcam Support** - No
**MSN Full Support** - Yes (No Webcam, Voice Chat)
**GTalk Full Support** - No
**Voice Chat** - No
**Protocols Supported** - MSN Protocol Only
**Send Files** - Yes
**Receive Files** - Yes
**Emoticons** - Yes
**Theme/Skin** - Yes (Only Chat)
**Language Support** - Yes
**Drag & Drop Support** - Yes
**Ubuntu Notification Support** - Yes (In Kubuntu)
**Last Updated (Since this Post)** - Version 2.0.6.1 - February 17, 2011
**Found in Ubuntu Repository** - Yes (Version 2.0.6-0ubuntu1)
**Now Playing Support** - Yes (With several players like Banshee)
**Plugins** - No
**PRO** - Many options for conversations, emoticons, chat styles, connectivity...
**CON** - No Video/Audio Support.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not certain that this will meet the needs of everyone, but Jitsi does do video chat.  I suspect that it will not do everything noted in the original question.

Jitsi (previously SIP Communicator) is an audio/video and chat communicator that supports protocols such as SIP, XMPP/Jabber, AIM/ICQ, Windows Live, Yahoo!, Bonjour and many other useful features.

Jitsi is Open Source / Free Software, and is available under the terms of the LGPL.

Features listed here:

http://www.jitsi.org/index.php/Main/Features

Comment: yep, videochat with other users using a client with the same protocol works eg. XMPP, but as the page shows MSN is **work in progress** and most people uses MSN for that exactly, no matter the client MSN videochat doesn't work. :(

Comment: I saw that too.  Hopefully that work progresses quickly.