# Windows Live Skin/Theme for Any IM  (aMSN, Empathy, emesene, etc)

Tags: windows, themes, instant-messaging

Today I was working on a place with 12 PCs and the only reason why I could not move the place from Windows to Ubuntu was that the users did not like how Amsns, Empathy or Emesene themes looked. They **ONLY** like the theme that uses Windows Live Messenger. Basically the Live Msn as it comes.

So I am looking for a theme that looks exactly like the latest version of Microsoft's Windows Live Messenger. At least in a way that fools the user completely. Amsn has some nice one but they look old and not like the new live msn. Where can I find a theme that looks like the windows live msn.

Just to not confuse with other themes, am talking about this one: [image]

Comment: Empathy doesn't support theming, same goes for emesene at least the new version doesn't, aMSN which is the closest one doesn't have any new new Live themes, pidgin doesn't support themes like that either.

Comment: I say try qnext which does seem to support themes, the defult theme looks like Live messeneger, although is still pretty green software.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/46848/instant-messaging-client/46858#46858

Answer (score 2, accepted):

his is a gallery with a good set of skins for aMsn http://madkat182.deviantart.com/gallery/24662213 you should find things like you are searching.

Answer (score 1):

aMSN with live theme:

[image]
    http://www.amsn-project.net/skins.php#26

Not perfect, but it's the most similar.

Answer (score 0):

Empathy does support themes. Adium-themes that is.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is if you install Windows Live Messenger with Playonlinux, and the problem gone. If the users prefer the original programs they work with, the Playonlinux is the most comfortable way to migrate exiting windows programs to linux. Mostly works without any problems.

Comment: Never thought of that actually. Nice input.