# Instant messaging clients

Tags: instant-messaging, msn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Available instant messaging clients](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46848/available-instant-messaging-clients)

Are there any instant messaging clients with custom emoticons like on the Windows Live Messenger or do I have to use Wine for it?

I've already tried Pidgin and the default Empathy clients. None have emoticons how I like them.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm just wondering if there's a simple IM client like Pidgin with custom emoticons that can be shared with people, who use WLM. (Pidgin can't do that. It has its own custom emoticons that others can't see.)

Comment: You can ask your friends to use [Pidgin for Windows](http://pidgin.im/download/windows/). By that way, both of you can use the custom emoticons!

Comment: I'm not going to make my friends settle for another IM client just because I have to.

Comment: I'm going to try Emesene.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Emesene](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/emesene/) or [Amsn](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/amsn/), because they both should feature emoticons customization. They are both available in the Ubuntu software center.

Answer (score 0):

Pidgin allows you to use [third-party custom smileys](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/ThirdPartySmileyThemes).
If you don't like them you always have the option to create your own theme.